# Xcode 6 is crashed

Tags: xcode6.1

I am using the Xcode 6 to develop the IOS application. there are more than 20 uiviewcontroller in storyboard. While duplicating the on the uiviewcontroller, Xcode 6 is crashed with following details.

```
Process:               Xcode [3249]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.0.1 (6528)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       712682811
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [3249]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2014-10-31 21:29:48.253 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        BA5EB3A3-EAF6-AC59-7BEB-054003FB610F


Time Awake Since Boot: 9600 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A317
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-6245/InterfaceBuilderKit/Document/IBDocument.m:2067
Details:  An instance of IBUIView with object ID 7tL-KA-q28 did not archive its child (IBLayoutConstraint) with an object of ID zUL-0Z-d57.
Object:   <IBStoryboardDocument: 0x7fb9e9c14200>
Method:   -documentArchiver:didArchiveObject:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb9e95388d0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
0  0x0000000108396f0a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
1  0x0000000107154baf _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
2  0x0000000107154e9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
3  0x000000011178ed32 -[IBDocument documentArchiver:didArchiveObject:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
4  0x00000001119c3eed -[IBStoryboardDocument documentArchiver:didArchiveObject:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
5  0x00000001117c821f __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
6  0x00000001117c749d -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
7  0x00000001117c7f62 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
8  0x00000001117c8f1f __59-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
9  0x00000001117c749d -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
10  0x00000001117c8d0d -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
11  0x00000001119c4736 __47-[IBStoryboardDocument archiveTopLevelObjects:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
12  0x00000001117c749d -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
13  0x00000001117c9a13 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveGroupWithName:forOptionalKey:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
14  0x00000001117c9c91 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveGroupWithName:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
15  0x00000001119c432b __47-[IBStoryboardDocument archiveTopLevelObjects:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
16  0x00000001117c749d -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
17  0x00000001117c9a13 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveGroupWithName:forOptionalKey:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
18  0x00000001117c9c91 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveGroupWithName:usingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
19  0x00000001119c4109 -[IBStoryboardDocument archiveTopLevelObjects:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
20  0x000000011178f01c -[IBDocument archiveAndVerifyArchivingOfTopLevelObjects:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
21  0x000000011178f761 -[IBDocument archivePlatformIndependentDataWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
22  0x00000001119c4fbb -[IBStoryboardDocument archivePlatformIndependentDataWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
23  0x000000011178f322 -[IBDocument archiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
24  0x00000001117c749d -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
25  0x00000001117c7770 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveDocument:withType:compatibilityVersion:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
26  0x00000001117c7a5a -[IBDocumentArchiver dataFromArchiveDocument:withType:compatibilityVersion:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
27  0x00000001117924d0 __46-[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:options:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
28  0x0000000111791e80 -[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
29  0x000000011179284c -[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
30  0x00007fff97904f57 -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
31  0x0000000111781d31 -[IBDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
32  0x00007fff97908053 -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] (in AppKit)
33  0x0000000111784fc6 -[IBDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
34  0x00007fff97906fbb -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:forceTemporaryDirectory:error:] (in AppKit)
35  0x00007fff97907ce3 -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] (in AppKit)
36  0x00007fff97907e51 -[NSDocument writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] (in AppKit)
37  0x000000010821f21f -[IDEEditorDocument writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] (in IDEKit)
38  0x00007fff97915115 __66-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_22307 (in AppKit)
39  0x00007fff97915016 __66-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke2304 (in AppKit)
40  0x00007fff97913436 __66-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke2176 (in AppKit)
41  0x00000001083cb887 __50-[IDEEditorDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:]_block_invoke74 (in IDEKit)
42  0x00007fff978fe999 -[NSDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:] (in AppKit)
43  0x0000000108203aac -[IDEEditorDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
44  0x00007fff9790e884 __101-[NSDocument _fileCoordinator:asynchronouslyCoordinateReadingContentsAndWritingItemAtURL:byAccessor:]_block_invoke_2 (in AppKit)
45  0x00000001083cbc28 __68-[IDEEditorDocument continueAsynchronousWorkOnMainThreadUsingBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)

.
.
.
```

How can i resolve crash issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with copy/pasting controllers between iPhone and iPad storyboards. Copy&paste worked ok but XCode crashed when I save storyboard. I was able to workaround issue by removing all constraints from copied controller. After that storyboard saved ok.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the crash occurred in -documentArchiver:didArchiveObject: and I guess it actually happened when you trying to save a modified storyboard file. I've encountered this bug recently and this is my workaround:

1. Identify the parts you want to modify in your storyboard (as a XML file, you can see them with any SCM, e.g. git)
2. Copy those parts as XML codes
3. Close that .storyboard file in your Interface Builder
4. Right click on that .storyboard file and choose Open As -> Source Code
5. Paste the codes between any  (if pasting to an empty storyboard file, then between )
6. Save the storyboard source code (XML)
7. Done.

Good luck. Happy Coding.